# How to make a plot invisible by default in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Clicking on the cogwheel 'settings' of an indicator on a chart pops up a dialog with a tab 'inputs' and a tab 'style'. Every style is preceded by a checkbox that controls the visibility of that particular plot. By default, all plots are visible. I want some plots to be hidden by default. The only way I know to do this is to manually uncheck some styles in the dialog, and then save these settings as the new default with the dropdownbox 'default' > 'save as default'.
But how can I do this in code? How can I set the default state of a plot to 'hidden' with pinescript?
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *display.none* for display parameter. For example:

```
plot(ema(close,200), title="EMA 200", color=color.red, display=display.none)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=false
plot(1, color=(a ? color.red : na))
```

I could also not figure this out... until I figured it out.

Comment: This is pinescript version 4

Comment: Thank you! I've got it working.
It still doesn't affect the checkbox in "style", basically I'm adding an entry in "Input" and that entry has a checkbox that I can control in pinescript. 
But it works, and that's what matters.  

    draw50=  input(title="50", type=input.bool, defval=false)
    plot(ema(close,50), color=(draw50 ? color.blue: na ), linewidth=2, title="50")

Thanks again!